# Altbeacon with Android Go 10

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-10.0, altbeacon, android-go

I'm wondering if anybody has used Altbeacon on an Android 10 Go edition device.

I have a working app that monitors and ranges iBeacons successfully on Android 10, it's been updated to have the required permissions and make it compatible with SDK29.

This app does not detect beacons on an Android 10 Go edition phone, so I thought before sinking a bunch of hours into debugging this, if anybody had any experience with this. I couldn't really find anything on Google :(

Thanks!

Comment: While I do not have an Android Go device, and don't know that this should work on your specific device, I don't know of any reason this shouldn't work in general on Android Go devices.  It is certainly possible there is a problem on the specific device you are testing.  Perhaps doesn't even support bluetooth?

Comment: @davidgyoung you're probably right, it being an issue with my specific device. It does support Bluetooth 5.2 though